# Interchangeable simulating and writing data to a file

Tags: r

I'm experimenting with R and I try to interchangeably simulate and write data to a file. I tried out many variants for example:

```
connection<-file("file.txt", open="w")
for (i in 1:2){
  X<-runif(3,0,1)
  writeLines(as.character(X), con=connection, sep="\n")
}
close(connection)
```

But what I get is

```
0.442033957922831
0.0713443560525775
0.950616024667397
0.0807233764789999
0.186026858631521
0.658676357707009
```

instead of something like

```
0.442033957922831 0.0713443560525775 0.950616024667397
0.0807233764789999 0.186026858631521 0.658676357707009
```

Could you explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You may need `writeLines(paste(X, collapse=" "), con = connectin, sep="\n")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `paste` the elements in 'X' to a single string and then use `sep='\n'`, otherwise after each element, it is jumping to nextline

```
connection<-file("file.txt", open="w")
for (i in 1:2){
   X<-runif(3,0,1)
   writeLines(paste(X, collapse=" "), con=connection, sep="\n")
 }
 close(connection)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much :) It seems I've solved the problem myself this way:
```connection<-file("plik.txt", open="w")
for (i in 1:10){
  X<-rnorm(3,0,1)
  
  write(X, ncolumns=3, file=connection, sep="\t")
}
close(connection)
```
Is one of these ways (mine or yours) preferable?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing line by line in a `for` loop we can create the string once and write it in the text file in one-go.

We can use `replicate` to repeat the `runif` code `n` times, `paste` the numbers row-wise, and paste them again collapsing with a new line character.

```
temp <- paste0(apply(t(replicate(2, runif(3,0,1))), 1, paste, collapse = ' '), 
                     collapse = '\n')
connection <- file("file.txt")
writeLines(temp, connection)
close(connection)
```

where `temp` gives us a string of length one which looks like this :

```
temp
#[1] "0.406911700032651 0.416268902365118 0.698520892066881\n0.96398281189613 0.834513065638021 0.655840792460367"
```

which looks in text file as :

```
cat(temp)
#0.406911700032651 0.416268902365118 0.698520892066881
#0.96398281189613 0.834513065638021 0.655840792460367
```